# localStorage запоминание вибрации при нажатии на кнопку после перезагрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Есть код

```
let doVibro = false;

document.getElementById("vibro_on").addEventListener('click', () => {
  doVibro = true;
});

document.getElementById("vibro_off").addEventListener('click', () => {
  doVibro = false;
});

document.getElementById("do-vibro").addEventListener('click', () => {
  doVibro ? navigator.vibrate([50]) : navigator.vibrate([0]);
});
<button id="vibro_on">ON</button>
<button id="vibro_off">OFF</button>

<button onclick="vibro()" id="do-vibro">TEST</button>
```

Нужно что бы при перезагрузки страницы оставалась вибрация включенной по нажатию на TESЕT тоесть устройство запоминало если включена вибрация то после перезагрузки страницы она оставалась включеной.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю вот ваш вариантик:

```js
let doVibro = Boolean(localStorage.getItem('doVibro') === '0' ? 0 : 1) || false;

document.getElementById("vibro_on").addEventListener('click', () => {
  switchVibro(true)
});

document.getElementById("vibro_off").addEventListener('click', () => {
  switchVibro(false)
});

document.getElementById("do-vibro").addEventListener('click', () => {
  doVibro ? navigator.vibrate([50]) : navigator.vibrate([0]);
});

function switchVibro(bool) {
  doVibro = Boolean(bool);
  localStorage.setItem('doVibro', bool ? '1' : '0')
}
```

Comment: Подскажите а как сделать что бы не по одному getElementById был вызов а всех сразу id c таким именем.
Тоесть я к этому id хочу подвязать кучу div и что бы вызывались все а не только первый div на странице.
А так получаеться что только первый работает по getElementById

Comment: @NikoPapchenko начнём с того что `id` **должен** быть уникальным, в этом суть `id`, есть вам нужно несколько элементов с одинаковым функционалом или стилями, тогда выдавайте им класс ([атрибут `class`](//developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class)). Далее если вы хотите выбрать, можно использовать два варианта, [`document.getElementsByClassName`](//developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) - чтобы найти элементы конкретно по классу, и [`querySelector`](//developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) чтобы по нескольким.

Comment: Если хотите более подробное объяснение, ищите в интернете: ['как выбрать несколько элементов? JS'](//www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2?%20JS) или задавай вопрос на Stackoverflow. (не рекомендованный вариант т.к. таких вопросов уже много)

Comment: А можно пожалуйста с document.getElementsByClassName или querySelector рабочий вариант моего кода? а то что то не получаеться(
хочу прикрутить с <div class="doVibro">TEST</div>

Comment: Если у вас просто много кнопок TEST то вот: `document.getElementsByClassName('doVibro').forEach(e => { e.addEventListener('click', /* какая-то функция */ })` или же через querySelector: `document.querySelector('.doVibro').forEach(e => { e.addEventListener('click', /* какая-то функция */ })`

Comment: @NikoPapchenko если даже так не поняли тогда уж лучше создавать отдельный вопрос, там вам либо скинут ссылку на подробное объяснение, либо сами объяснят.

Comment: все разобрался Спасибо!